# Where are the 4.3 dungeons actually accessed from?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Patch 4.3 is adding three new dungeons to the game:

- Well of Eternity, taking place in the Night Elf city of Zin-Azshari immediately prior to the city's destruction and transformation into the Maelstrom
- Hour of Twilight, wherein Thrall's passage to Wyrmrest Temple must be assured during Deathwing's assault on the Dragonblight
- End Time, which is a distant future version of the Dragonblight following Deathwing's ultimate success and eventual suicide

While it's pretty likely that the vast majority of players will get to these dungeons through the dungeon finder, it should still be possible to reach them manually. Where are they actually accessed from? "Current" Dragonblight, or Caverns of Time, or what?

Bonus question: where is the raid Dragon Soul accessed from, for that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new dungeon entrances will be located in the Caverns of Time. However the quest for the rogue legendary weapon [Fangs of the Father](http://www.wowpedia.org/Fangs_of_the_Father) will be in the Wyrmrest temple from Lord Afrasastrasz. The dungeons have a quest line so you progress through them in order, End Time then Well of Eternity and finally Hour of Twilight. The Dragon Soul Raid will pick up right where the Hour of Twilight ends. It will be an outdoor raid that takes place in several locations. The entrance will also be located in the Caverns of time like the 5 man dungeons. Locations of the raid include Wyrmrest temple, Eye of Eternity, and finally the Malestrom. The [Deathwing Fight](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2qRxbpL2vw) is said to be and easy one especially the [Malestrom Encounter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezBr3KzWJHo) but we will see soon enough. Good Luck

Answer (score 4):

All of the new instanced content that came out with patch 4.3 is accessible from the **Caverns of Time**.

The first 5-man dungeon in the series, **End Time**, is located in a new wing of the caverns identifiable by the burning trees outside of the entrance. The third dungeon, **Hour of Twilight**, and the raid instance, **Dragon Soul**, are  also located in this wing.

The second dungeon, **Well of Eternity**, is accessed across the cavern in its own section.